# Is it necessary to config dfs.namenode.name.dir when HDFS QJM is enabled

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When HDFS NameNode HA with QJM is enabled, we have configured `dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir`, we suppose edit logs should be written to at least two QJM node.

In this case, is it necessary to config `dfs.namenode.name.dir` or `dfs.namenode.edits.dir`, so NameNode can write edit log to local disk? As I know, edit log has a big performance impact on NameNode.